# jQuery draggable applying multiple clicks after drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm half way through updating [my website](http://www.tonygroth.com/castle_builder/version_2.htm) and I've ran into an issue I can't seem to figure out. If you click the green button labeled "Alchemy Lab" an Alchemy Lab will pop up. After that if you drag the Lab once and click the red and green arrows in the Lab the counter works like it should with a max of 10. If you drag the Lab around 2 more times and then click the green or red arrow the count is off by 3. So every time you drop the Lab it adds another click on click. Any ideas on why or how to fix it? Thanks in advanced.

javascript:

```
    function handleNewClicks() {
    $(".pro_cell_3").click(function () {
        var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(), 10);
        var maxUp = 10;

        if (currentUp == maxUp) {
            $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text("1");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(currentUp + 1);
        }

    });
    $(".pro_cell_4").click(function () {
        var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(), 10);
        var maxUp = 10;

        if ((currentUp - 1) == 0) {
            $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(maxUp);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(currentUp - 1);
        }
    });
    $(".up_cell_3").click(function () {
        var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(), 10);
        var maxUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').attr("max"), 10);
        var className = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
        className = className.replace("ui-draggable ", "");

        if (currentUp == maxUp) {
            $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text("1");
            $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_1.png)' });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(currentUp + 1);
            $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + (currentUp + 1) + '.png)' });
        }

    });
    $(".up_cell_4").click(function () {
        var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(), 10);
        var maxUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').attr("max"), 10);
        var className = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
        className = className.replace("ui-draggable ", "");

        if ((currentUp - 1) == 0) {
            $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(maxUp);
            $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + maxUp + '.png)' });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(currentUp - 1);
            $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + (currentUp - 1) + '.png)' });
        }

    });
}

function proCoding() {    
    proWrap = document.createElement('div');
    $(proWrap).attr('class', 'pro_wrap');
    proCell1 = document.createElement('span');
    $(proCell1).attr('class', 'pro_cell_1');
    proCell2 = document.createElement('span');
    $(proCell2).attr('class', 'pro_cell_2');
    proCell3 = document.createElement('span');
    $(proCell3).attr('class', 'pro_cell_3');
    proCell4 = document.createElement('span');
    $(proCell4).attr('class', 'pro_cell_4');

    proCell2.innerText = "1";
    proWrap.appendChild(proCell1);
    proWrap.appendChild(proCell2);
    proWrap.appendChild(proCell3);
    proWrap.appendChild(proCell4);
}

function upCoding() {
    pos_top = $(window).scrollTop() + top_off_set;
    pos_left = $(window).scrollLeft() + left_off_set;

    upWrap = document.createElement('div');
    $(upWrap).attr('class', 'up_wrap');
    upCell1 = document.createElement('span');
    $(upCell1).attr('class', 'up_cell_1');
    upCell2 = document.createElement('span');
    $(upCell2).attr('class', 'up_cell_2');
    $(upCell2).attr('max', '10');
    upCell3 = document.createElement('span');
    $(upCell3).attr('class', 'up_cell_3');
    upCell4 = document.createElement('span');
    $(upCell4).attr('class', 'up_cell_4');

    upCell2.innerText = "1";
    upWrap.appendChild(upCell1);
    upWrap.appendChild(upCell2);
    upWrap.appendChild(upCell3);
    upWrap.appendChild(upCell4);

    newLab = document.createElement('div');
}

$(".nav_alchemy_lab").click(function () {
    proCoding();
    upCoding();
    newLab.appendChild(proWrap);
    newLab.appendChild(upWrap);

    $(newLab).attr('class', 'ui-draggable alchemy_lab').appendTo('#cardPile').css({ 'top': pos_top, 'left': pos_left, 'background-image': 'url(images/alchemy_lab_1.png)' }).draggable({
        containment: '#content', snap: true, stack: '#cardPile div', cursor: 'move',
        start: function (e) {

        },
        stop: function (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                handleNewClicks()
            }, 1);
        }
    })

});

$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'move'
});

$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    drop: handleCardDrop
});

function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).css('top', $(this).position().top);
    var divWidth = ui.draggable.width();
    var divLeft = $(this).position().left;
    if (divWidth == 100) {
        divLeft -= 0;
    } else if (divWidth == 200) {
        divLeft -= 100;
    } else if (divWidth == 300) {
        divLeft -= 100;
    } else {
        divLeft -= 0;
    }
    $(ui.draggable).css('left', divLeft);
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not expecting people to browse your site's source. Please post relevant code.

Comment: I recommend you try posting what you think is the relevant code that is producing the error and preferably what have you tried to do to solve it. This is not a site where you get work done for free, it's about collaboration.

Comment: I added the relevant javascript but half of the html is create based off what you click and the other half is a massive 7x8 grid so yes you'll need a plugin like figbug. I am not trying to get anyone to look at my website... the website has a specific audience that I highly doubt anyone on here would even have an interest in, I'm just looking to fix my code.

Comment: also If you look at the code you'd see I've done a little bit of coding myself on the project so I don't need anyone to do my work for me, just looking for some pointers.

Comment: I just added a breakpoint in the code using the Web Inspector in Chrome. If you try it (Firebug should have breakpoints too), you'll see the function that increments the counter actually runs multiple times. If you find what's causing that, you'll fix the problem.

Comment: I added an alert and noticed that. I have no idea whats causing it to run multiple times, I would assume it has to do with the drop event.

Comment: @Dell I was not trying to be disrespectful at all, just pointing out that this question, might imply too much work on the answerers behalf as it was (or maybe is), if that was the case, that would not help you at all to get your answer, as a general rule, the more help you give possible answerers, and the closer you put them to a solution, more probable it will be that you get a great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you finish dragging something, you run the function `handleNewClicks()`.

```
$(newLab).attr('class', 'ui-draggable alchemy_lab').appendTo('#cardPile').css({ 'top': pos_top, 'left': pos_left, 'background-image': 'url(images/alchemy_lab_1.png)' }).draggable({
            containment: '#content', snap: true, stack: '#cardPile div', cursor: 'move',
            start: function (e) {

            },
            stop: function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    handleNewClicks()
                }, 1);
            }
        })
```

In addition, this function binds events to the cells. When you bind the events to the cells multiple times, they are getting called more than once. You only need to run `handleNewClicks()` once when initializing the alchemy lab.

```
function handleNewClicks() {
        $(".pro_cell_3").click(function () {
            var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(), 10);
            var maxUp = 10;

            if (currentUp == maxUp) {
                $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text("1");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(currentUp + 1);
            }

        });
        $(".pro_cell_4").click(function () {
            var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(), 10);
            var maxUp = 10;

            if ((currentUp - 1) == 0) {
                $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(maxUp);
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.pro_cell_2').text(currentUp - 1);
            }
        });
        $(".up_cell_3").click(function () {
            var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(), 10);
            var maxUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').attr("max"), 10);
            var className = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
            className = className.replace("ui-draggable ", "");

            if (currentUp == maxUp) {
                $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text("1");
                $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_1.png)' });
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(currentUp + 1);
                $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + (currentUp + 1) + '.png)' });
            }

        });
        $(".up_cell_4").click(function () {
            var currentUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(), 10);
            var maxUp = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').attr("max"), 10);
            var className = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
            className = className.replace("ui-draggable ", "");

            if ((currentUp - 1) == 0) {
                $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(maxUp);
                $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + maxUp + '.png)' });
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.up_cell_2').text(currentUp - 1);
                $(this).parent().parent().css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/' + className + '_' + (currentUp - 1) + '.png)' });
            }

        });
    }
```

Basically, to fix this, you could change the following function to what I have below:

```
$(".nav_alchemy_lab").click(function () {
        proCoding();
        upCoding();
        newLab.appendChild(proWrap);
        newLab.appendChild(upWrap);



    $(newLab).attr('class', 'ui-draggable alchemy_lab').appendTo('#cardPile').css({ 'top': pos_top, 'left': pos_left, 'background-image': 'url(images/alchemy_lab_1.png)' }).draggable({
                containment: '#content', snap: true, stack: '#cardPile div', cursor: 'move'
            });

handleNewClicks()

    });
```

This is all untested.

Comment: Wow... yeah thats it. It does create an issue when you have multiple Labs but I'll mess with that some and see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: If it's because the events are not bound to new labs, try using jQuery's Live feature: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thats what I was thinking but... I didn't know .live() existed, still learning here. Thank you very much, you answered my question and my question in my question! lol thanks again.